# How to can i put two text lines in the same link?

Tags: html, css, overlay

I have this:

```
<td>                            
    <a id="linkbt_cashier" href="#" class="link_ball" style="font-size: 16px;margin-right:20px;">Add Credits</a>
</td>
```

My image is 127x127 and i want two text lines inside image and not just one, like this:

```
  Add
Credits
```

I try with line-height and height but did´t work because the two words are to small for the height of the image.

Sorry for noob question and thanks for the helping.

Comment: I have this problem solved. Now I need help to align the text in the right place. With the line-height testing from 0 to 200px the best I get was the lines from the right distance but they are in the top of the image.

Comment: Solved! Adding padding-top and changing height, puts the text in the right place. Thank!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<a>` tag is basically an inline element. The width of this element is dependent on the anchor text length. So use `display: inline-block` and specify a width.

Quoting Quirksmode:

> The real use of this value is when you want to give an inline element a width. In some circumstances some browsers don't allow a width on a real inline element, but if you switch to display: inline-block you are allowed to set a width.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display:block` on the A-tag and set a `width:` and allow word-wrap to occur by itself in the restricted space, or embed a `<br />` in your text.

Comment: You need to adjust the line-height for the wrapping element.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use br, it's work for me

```
<td>                            
    <a id="linkbt_cashier" href="#" class="link_ball" style="font-size: 16px;margin-right:20px;">Add <br />Credits</a>
</td>
```

Comment: If you get downvoted, it won't be from me. Double check your `</br>`

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add a break (<br />) inside the text.  Change your code to the following:

```
<td>                            
    <a id="linkbt_cashier" href="#" class="link_ball" style="font-size: 16px;margin-right:20px;">Add<br />Credits</a>
</td>
```

Hope this helps.